# Are storage crates for hard drives on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Referencing [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6939/looking-for-a-storage-case-for-multiple-hard-drives?noredirect=1#comment11695_6939).

Guy is asking about where to store unused drives.

My understanding of current scope is that questions concerning electronic devices that connect or communicate with computers are on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree. Your understanding is correct in my view; what's being requested here is analogous to a desk - important for computing, yes, but out of scope for this site.

Comment: Just checking..

Comment: Please cite the rule(s) from the help center that support the question is off-topic.

Comment: @jia103 http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. *"an electronic item that is, interfaces with, or connects to a computer to operate".* And the [linked meta question](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware).

Comment: The linked meta question is referenced on the page in the prior sentence for details on what hardware is accepted. This question has two answers, both of which have had the same number of up-votes at the time I posted my question. The latter from @Cfinley adds "things related to hardware...specifically designed to be used with hardware".

Additionally, I see nothing on the http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask page that explicitly prohibits this question.

Comment: @jia103 The accepted answer on that meta question is the one that details current policy, which was picked because it had the highest score at the time. We can revisit that policy if you'd like, but you'll need to ask a new meta question about it.